# How to handle errors in micronaut rest service?

Tags: rest, kotlin, error-handling, reactive, micronaut

I'm new to micronaut and I try to implement a simple use-case:
have a rest endpoint that calls another rest service and return the result to the user (in practice there will be some processing of the result before handing it back but for simplicity this example suffices).

Here is my code:

```
@Controller("/hello")
class HelloController(private val echoClient: EchoClient) {

    @Get
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun hello() = echoClient.echo("hello")
}

@Client(id = "http://localhost:7893/")
interface EchoClient {

    @Post("/") @SingleResult
    fun echo(@Body text: String): Publisher<String>
}
```

The service on port 7893 is a simple echo server that returns whatever you send to it.

When I call this endpoint from my browser (`http://localhost:8080/hello`), everything works as expected.

But when I throw a lot of requests to it using Apeche JMeter, every now and then I see an error in the console and the request in JMeter keeps hanging until I stop it manually. Here is the error I get:

```
19:08:22.362 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-9] ERROR reactor.core.publisher.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
java.lang.IllegalStateException: onNext before request?
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.handler.PipeliningServerHandler$StreamingOutboundHandler.onNext(PipeliningServerHandler.java:812)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.handler.PipeliningServerHandler$StreamingOutboundHandler.onNext(PipeliningServerHandler.java:774)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$LazySendingSubscriber.onNext(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:628)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$LazySendingSubscriber.onNext(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:570)
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.JsonSubscriber.onComplete(JsonSubscriber.java:84)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchMapNoPrefetch$SwitchMapMain.onComplete(FluxSwitchMapNoPrefetch.java:264)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$JustPublisher$1.request(Publishers.java:606)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchMapNoPrefetch$SwitchMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxSwitchMapNoPrefetch.java:147)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:92)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.publisher.Publishers$JustPublisher.subscribe(Publishers.java:594)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.propagation.ReactivePropagation$1.subscribe(ReactivePropagation.java:54)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.propagation.ReactivePropagation$1.subscribe(ReactivePropagation.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSource.subscribe(FluxSource.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8773)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.DelegateStreamedHttpResponse.subscribe(DelegateStreamedHttpResponse.java:48)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.writeStreamedWithErrorHandling(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:457)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.encodeHttpResponse(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:298)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.writeResponse(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:236)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyRequestLifecycle.lambda$handleNormal$0(NettyRequestLifecycle.java:87)
    at io.micronaut.http.reactive.execution.ReactorExecutionFlowImpl$1.onComplete(ReactorExecutionFlowImpl.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:159)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.request(FluxContextWrite.java:136)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxOnErrorResume.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxContextWrite.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.propagation.ReactivePropagation$1.subscribe(ReactivePropagation.java:54)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.propagation.ReactivePropagation$1.subscribe(ReactivePropagation.java:61)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFromPublisher.subscribe(MonoFromPublisher.java:67)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at io.micronaut.http.reactive.execution.ReactorExecutionFlowImpl.onComplete(ReactorExecutionFlowImpl.java:89)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyRequestLifecycle.handleNormal(NettyRequestLifecycle.java:87)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.accept(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:223)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.websocket.NettyServerWebSocketUpgradeHandler.accept(NettyServerWebSocketUpgradeHandler.java:156)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.handler.PipeliningServerHandler$MessageInboundHandler.read(PipeliningServerHandler.java:344)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.handler.PipeliningServerHandler.channelRead(PipeliningServerHandler.java:202)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.onHttpRequestChannelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:160)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:83)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

What should I do so that the endpoint returns a decent error (e.g. http 400) instead of hanging there?

- micronaut: 4.0.0-M5
- java: 20.0.1-graal
- kotlin: 1.9.0-RC

Comment: Please add info about your environment (Micronaut-version, JDK etc.) to your question. BR